# Filtered Views VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an automated filed that comes out with a row (4) of headers

the first column (A) contains different categories (types of payment), in base of the specific type I would run a different test based on a certain sheet contained into the file I'm working on.

What am I doing at the moment is basically create a filter (of the first column A) based on the type of payment I want to check, create a temporary sheet, copy paste this filtered view, work on that with the checks and then copy/paste the result (contained in the column R) into the main sheet.

The problem comes out in the last part, when I want to copy paste, because of the filtered view I can't Just go to the first free cell under the header of R and copy paste, because the system doesn't understand I'm moving into a filtered view. I have to be sure that I'm copy pasting the correct results in base of the value (string) contained into the A column), can you help me to solve it please?.

Another way is to do a for each loop, but actually I'm not sure about how to structure it.

Here we have the part of the code i'm working on

```
Sub Payexample()
' normal cleaning procedures
    Sheets("Payexample").Select
    Rows("1:10").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="AED", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"


    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$A$500").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Payfort"
    Range("A5 : N5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Payfort momentary"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("$M$1").Formula = Range("B1") & (",") & Range("M1")

    Dim Lastrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Lastrow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("O1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]-VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'PayFort'!B:J,9,FALSE)<=0.99, ""Payfort          Payment Checked"", ""Manual Verification Needed"")"
    Range("O1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("O1:O" & Lastrow)
        Range("O1:O" & Lastrow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$A$500").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Payfort"

    Range("R5").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

        'Sheets("Payfort Momentary").Select
        'ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry docendo, I added the suggested tags. My bad. Thanks for the edit

Comment: If I understand correctly, when you are trying to paste the results back into the filtered data, Excel needs to split that data up into separate ranges, which it can't do with an out of the box paste. You could consider whether the checks can be done in VBA without the need to create a temp sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do mostly what you are after but I wasn't sure what you want to do with your formulas, hopefully you'll be able to work out what you want to do with them from here:

```
Sub Payexample()
Dim rngCheck As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim rowNum As Long
' normal cleaning procedures
    Sheets("Payexample").Select
    Rows("1:10").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="AED", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    With ActiveSheet
        rngCheck = .Range("$A$4:$A$500")
        For Each r In rngCheck.Rows ' Loop through the rows in your data area
            rowNum = r.Row
            If .Range("A" & rowNum) = "Payfort" Then
                ' Either
                .Range("R" & rowNum).Formula = "" ' Your formula here
                .Range("R" & rowNum) = .Range("R" & rowNum).Value ' Change formula to value
                ' Or
                .Range("R" & rowNum) = ' Do calculations in VBA without formula
            End If
        Next r
    End With

End Sub
```